# Spring batch ItemWriter exception is killing job

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I have a spring batch application which will read data through rest API and write the data in DB.

Below is my code.

Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("batchJob")
public Job batchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(batchJobExecutionListener)
            .start(firstStep)
            .next(secondStep)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step firstStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("firstStep").<Input, Output>chunk(AppConst.BATCH_CHUNK)
            .reader(firstReader)
            .processor(firstProcessor)
            .writer(firstWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .skipLimit(99999)
            .listener(new FirstSkipListener())
            .build();
}
```

FirstSkipListener.class:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FirstSkipListener implements SkipListener<Input, Output> {

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Input arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        // Do nothing in onSkipInProcess
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable arg0) {
        // Do nothing in onSkipInRead
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Output output, Throwable arg1) {
        log.error("Skipped output = {} ", output);
    }

}
```

FirstWriter.class:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FirstWriter implements ItemWriter<Output> {

    @Autowired
    private OutputRepository outputRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private BatchRunRepository batchRunRepository;
    
    private Integer batchId;
    
    private Integer updateCount;
    
    /**
     * This method will write output list in db.
     * @param outputs
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Output> outputs) {
        log.info("Start writing output data.");
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(outputs)) {
            try {
                updateCount = outputs.size();
                outputRepository.saveAll(outputs);
                outputRepository.flush();
                log.info("End writing output data.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error occured while writing output data: {}", e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.info("No data to be writtern for output.");
        }
    }
}
```

OutputRepository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface OutputRepository extends JpaRepository<Output, Long> {
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        default_schema: my_schema
        format_sql: true
        jdbc: 
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
  batch:
    initialize-schema: always
    initializer:
      enabled: false
    job:
      enabled: false
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent_output: true
  profiles: local
    
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=my_schema
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
    platform: postgres
  jpa:             
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

Now when I run my job, I am getting below exception.

```
2020-10-28 17:56:01.520  INFO [my-app,5764b6867c680cf1,5764b6867c680cf1,false] 17548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.c.d.m.b.job.writer.FirstWriter     : Start writing output data.
2020-10-28 17:56:02.108 ERROR [my-app,5764b6867c680cf1,5764b6867c680cf1,false] 17548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "output_name" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (486, null, 4, null, null, null, null, Need Description, data, null, 439e00ef-45d5-3a4b-ab65-f620f641b6d3, f, A, user, 2020-10-28 17:56:02.101, 2020-10-28 17:56:02.101, user, null, ).
2020-10-28 17:56:02.118 ERROR [my-app,5764b6867c680cf1,5764b6867c680cf1,false] 17548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.c.d.m.b.job.writer.FirstWriter     : Error occured while writing output data: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [output_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2020-10-28 17:56:02.250 ERROR [my-app,5764b6867c680cf1,5764b6867c680cf1,false] 17548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : JobRepository failure forcing rollback

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:236) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:163) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
```

In my code I am setting skip policy and I am expecting if I initially pass 10 elements in outputs list and 5th record has an issue then, spring batch should throw exception & retry the calling write method 10 times. So that only one record will get skipped and other 9 will persist in database.

But in my case, my batch application is stopping at all. It is not even able to update BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table which is maintained by sprint.

Please note that I am using JPA repository & not trying to manage transaction anywhere. Not even provided transaction manager considering spring will manage it on my behalf.

Comment: the root cause is "*ERROR: null value in column "output_name" violates not-null constraint*"

Comment: I can not be sure of the data coming through API. And I need to insert in DB. of course there will some records which might throw an exception.

Comment: Well, the definition of a transaction is  "either all commands succeed or none". If your transaction involves some commands that fail you can't expect the others to succeed. If it's acceptable that some statements are successful and other are not, you can't do everything in a single transaction. You need to use one transaction per insert (e.g. autocommit = on)

Comment: No I am not saying that the txn should succeed. I am saying that I have implemented skip listener which should come into picture when first call to write failed. Let's say I sent 10 items in write method & it failed due to 5th record, then spring batch should call write method by passing one by one item. Only failure item should be skipped.

Comment: That would require the use of savepoints around each statement, I have no idea how to enable that in Spring or JPA

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the error. In my write class I have a catch block which I am using to print and exception. I removed try catch block & let spring batch find an exception & call skip listener.